# jquery.event.drag TypeError: $event.fixHooks is undefined

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, carousel

I'm playing around with the roundabout plugin for jquery. I wanted to add 3dubs drag and drop plugin to augment it but I keep getting a $event.fixHooks error. Can someone explain what that error is and if there's a fix?

Here's my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.roundabout.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.event.drop-2.2.js"></script> 
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('ul').roundabout();
   });
</script>

<style type="text/css">

* { 

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

#carousel { 

    margin: 300px 0 0 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

.roundabout-holder {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 800px;
}

.roundabout-moveable-item {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.roundabout-in-focus {
  cursor: auto;
}
</style> 

<title>Round About Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="carousel">

    <ul>
        <li>Carousel Item 1</li>
        <li>Carousel Item 2</li>
        <li>Carousel Item 3</li>
        <li>Carousel Item 4</li>
        <li>Carousel Item 5</li>
        <li>Carousel Item 6</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the full error:

```
TypeError: $event.fixHooks is undefined

 filter: function( event, orig ) {
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use jQuery >= 1.7 and < 3.*

There is no `fixHooks` in jQuery 1.6.2.

There should be a mention on the plugin's home page about the required jQuery version.